# my nginx doesn't display php file at centos7

Tags: nginx, centos7

I installed nginx at centos7(VPS) I know this question are often asked here. I've been searching solution but my nginx get worse. so I post here.
when first time I tried open a php file broswer asked file download insted of display. I searched solution at web and adjust code. after that.
I can display "Welcome to nginx！" but when I tried to open index.php , I got "An error occurred." That what I made a file that

Could you teach me what is wrong my code please?

```
location ~ \.php$ {

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

And this is my log

```
2019/04/14 03:33:51 [error] 3445#3445: *10 connect() failed
 (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 140.xxx.xxx.x, server: localhost, request: 
"GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.x"
```

Comment: The first problem is that your error log does not match the configuration you posted. One uses `unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock` and the other `127.0.0.1:9000`. Where is php-fpm listening? Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to see the entire configuration that Nginx is using.

Comment: @Richard Smith Thank you for answering me. It worked. I dont't know why but it went good. I appreciate your comment. Thank you so much.